# How to Interact with a program using WSH -Jscript

Tags: javascript, desktop-application, wsh, interaction

I am trying to click a button on an application in the systray using WSH. Is this possible? Could somebody provide an example written in Jscript please? THANKS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible unless the program itself provides COM instrumentation (Office and IE does this for instance). The large majority of programs cannot be instrumented. And WSH provides very basic shell access, and as far as I know, it provides no access at all to the notification area.

You'll likely want some other tool that does this. While I'm not sure of an exact program, I'm sure google can yield something in the region of "windows automation."

Comment: He did give you the answer: No. :-)